# MKMapItem error in swift 2.0

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, mkmapitem

When I run the following code, I get the error "Cannot call value of non function type 'MKMapItem?'

```
request.source(MKMapItem.mapItemForCurrentLocation())
```

It worked fine in swift 1.2
what has changed ?

Comment: What is `request` and `source()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift 2 (Xcode Beta 5), `source` is now a property of `MKDirectionsRequest`:

Hence, instead of:

```
request.source(MKMapItem.mapItemForCurrentLocation())
```

It is now:

```
request.source = MKMapItem.mapItemForCurrentLocation()
```